# Strategies and Indicator Placement

Tags: pine-script

New to pine script so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Say I have a strategy that I would like to plot a moving average and MACD. It seems that it is not possible get the moving average on the price panel and the MACD on a separate panel? If I use overlay = true everything is on the price panel. If I use overlay = false, everything is squished together on a secondary panel.

Would the best way to have the indicators show as I would be to have the strategy only plot say the MACD and then add the moving average indicator to the chart outside of the strategy for visual purposes?

Comment: Not possible. The single option for a script that is loaded on a separate pane to plot/draw somthing on the chart pane at the same time - is to use 'barcolor()' function that will assign colors to price bars/candles. Any 'plot()', 'plotshape()' etc will be only drawn on the indicator's pane.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is yet another PineScript limitation, you can only plot everything as an overlay, or everything as a separate panel.